# Employee sends form to manage approval

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

The employee sends the form to the manager for approval, 
and the manager login account index displays the approval form sent by different employees in the same department.
These codes now display the form and cannot display different names.
How to modify this code.

*Model:*

```cs
public class RequesViewModel
{
    public RequesViewModel()
    {
        this.ReApproval = new List<Reimbursement.Models.Reimbursement>();
        }
        public int ReimbursementID { get; set; }
        public string StaffId { get; set; }
        //public string  StaffName { get; set; }
        public string  JobPositionName { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public List<Reimbursement.Models.Reimbursement> ReApproval { get; set; }

}
```

*Controller:*

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var staffName = User.Identity.Name;
    var staffId = db.Staffs.Where(a => a.UserName == staffName).FirstOrDefault();
    var req = db.RequestForApprovals.Where(f => f.Id.ToString() == staffId.Id).ToString();
    RequesViewModel Re = new RequesViewModel();
    {

    }
    return View(db.RequestForApprovals.ToList());
}
```

*View:*

```html
@model IEnumerable<Reimbursement.Models.RequestForApproval>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>StaffId</th>
        <th>Staff Fname</th>
        <th>RequestDate</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reimbursement.Id) 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Staff.Fname) 
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Staff.Lname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: The `RequestViewModel` object that you have created in the `controller` is completely empty. The values of the variables that you have assigned in the controller have local scope, you need to assign those values to `Model variables` in order to render them in `view`

Kindly do refer, [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and improve up your question.